# Interpret TraditionalForm as InputForm

Tags: front-end

[image: Every Time]

Every time I execute a command in *Mathematica*, it prompts me whether I would like it to remember my decision to convert TraditionalForm to InputForm. Sadly it doesn't remember my decision ?

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 2):

Try manually changing the corresponding option in the "Option Inpector". You can open it by going to Format -> Option Inspector in the menu.

The option is called `TradiotionalFormEvaluationWarning` and you should set it to `False`. Make sure you are on "Global Preferences" in the leftmost dropdown.

Screenshot:

[image]